# Trying to Average number of accounts by hour, day of week, and month

Tags: tableau-api, hour

I'm in healthcare and we're trying to assess the number of discharges we have per hour of day, but we'd also like to be able to filter them down by day of week, or specific month, or even a particular day of week in a particular month (e.g. " what is the average number of discharges per hour on Mondays in January?")

I'm confident that Tableau can do this, but haven't been able to make the averages show up in my line graph... every time that I convert it from COUNT to AVG, the line simply goes straight. I got close when I did a table calculation to find the Average (dividing the count per hour by the number of days captured in the report), but when I add a filter for either the month or day of week, selecting one of the options of the filter reduces the total number that is being counted, rather than re-averaging the non-filtered items. (i.e. if the average of the 7 days of the week is "10" for a particular hour, and I deselect the first three days of the week, it's now saying that my average for that hour is roughly 6, despite the fact that all of the days are very close to 10 at that hour.)

Currently, my data table has the following columns:

```
Account#/MonthYear/HourOfDay/DayOfWeek
ex.12345678/ Jan-17  /   12    /Sunday
```

Comment: Please try to make an MCVE with the code you have tried, the one which "got close". Of course, do not provide personal patient data, make some up which demonstrate your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a few calculated fields to differentiate the parts of the calendar you might want to filter/aggregate on. Mixing the month and day of the week with filtering is pretty straight forward with the calculated fields. Then do standard summing to get what you are looking for because an average count of records is always one unless you are throwing some other calculation into the mix. I threw a quick example up on [Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/views/DischargeTest/Discharges?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes) for you to get the idea.

Comment: I have almost exactly what you put together. However, what I'm looking for are the averages, not just the counts.

Comment: What specific average(s) are you looking for?